# ssh connection with -s and sftp hangs when reaching subsystem request accepted on channel 0

Tags: ssh, sftp

I've run into this strange issue of not being able to connect with `ssh user@domain -s sftp`.

**sshd_config** on target specifies `Subsystem sftp /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server`, the sftp-server file is there and I've created symlinks to it in /usr/bin, /usr/sbin etc. as so `which sftp-server` shows correct executable.

Plain `sftp user@domain` and `ssh user@domain` are working without problems.

running with `-vvv`reaches `debug2: subsystem request accepted on channel 0` and hands up, until I `ctrl+c`-it.

There are no overshadowing configurations for sshd on target and ssh on client.

On target `/var/log/secure` for `[sshd]` ends on :

```
sshd[324070]: debug3: send packet: type 99
sshd[324070]: debug3: mm_request_receive entering
sshd[324070]: debug3: monitor_read: checking request 124
```

sshd logs shows no errors with connection.

sshd_config have only one Subsystem parameter defined for sftp and really whole config is unmodified (default).

I've tried connecting to these targets OSs : Red Hat 8.6, Ubuntu 22.04 and MacOS 13.2.1 (zsh 5.8.1).

I want to be able to use ssh with `-s` and to defined multiple `Subsystem`s.

Based on this: https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/ssh-the-secure/0596008953/ch05s08.html I understand that my usage of this flag is correct as the desired subsystem should be placed in ssh call as remote-command.

Please correct me if I am wrong (with the usage) and maybe preferably point out any sources that might help with making this work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ssh user@domain -s sftp` is expected to "hang". The SFTP protocol is binary. You can hardly talk to it in `ssh` terminal.

If your aim was to try/test SFTP using custom subsystem name, use the `-s` switch with `sftp`:

```
sftp user@example.com -s sftp
```

---

If you wonder what's the `-s` for in `ssh`:  The SSH protocol has the "subsystem API". The `-s` switch is just an `ssh` interface to that API. The only standard use of the subsystem API in SSH is SFTP. There is imo no practical use of the `ssh -s` switch with the SFTP, as SFTP is binary protocol. No other standard use of SSH subsystems has even emerged, afaik. But simply OpenSSH `ssh` has the switch just in case there's a use for it. There are dozens of other `ssh` options that you probably never use. But they are there, for the rare cases you might need them.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145479/discussion-on-answer-by-martin-prikryl-ssh-connection-with-s-and-sftp-hangs-whe); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.